# Why it's not possible to add multiple new objects to a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to add multiple custom objects to Scala List. I am getting error in Scala worksheet while:

```
var l: List[(Char, Int)]= List(new ('A', 2), new ('B', 1) )
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Remove the `new` keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct Tuple2 without new

```
 var l: List[(Char, Int)]= List(('A', 2), ('B', 1) )
```

Comment: It works but why I cannot use `new` since it's the way to create new object in Java?

Comment: @RCola If you **really** want to use the `new` keyword, use the `Tuple2` constructor directly: `new Tuple2('A', 2)`. But why make the code uglier, when the compiler will automatically expand it for you later?

Comment: @RCola: I'm pretty sure that `new ('A', 2)` is an error in Java as well.

Comment: In fact, it's the *same* error in Java ("`error: <identifier> expected`") as in Scala ("`error: identifier expected but character literal found.`").